# Pytorch и PyCharm community. Debugging

Tags: отладка, pycharm, pytorch

Подскажите, почему Pycharm и Pytorch "не дружат" когда пытаешься в PyCharm выполнить программу в отладчике? Работаю под Linux Mint. Все время вылетает ошибка что не хватает какой нибудь библиотеки, хотя они есть. И пути в переменных окружения уже правил. Ставил pytorch с помощью conda. Возможно под виндами работает нормально? Кто как обходил ошибки при отладке?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была с библиотекой libstdc++.so.6.

Как вылечить эту проблему  изложено по ссылке https://www.programmersought.com/article/41851413652/